# My Xubuntu 20.04 LTS is stuck in a login loop, can't login through shell doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, login, xfce

My Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is stuck in a login loop whenever I enter my password it the screen goes black, it flashes me an error, and then takes me back to the login. when I open the shell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, it asks for my login and password, and even when I enter the correct login info it says its incorrect. I've looked it up on ask ubuntu and just the internet in general, but nothing worked. anybody got any ideas? (I'm using an Dell Inspiron N50-something or other, and I've tried with XFCE and Xubuntu sessions.)

Comment: What is the error it flashes up?

Comment: its to fast to read